# Cluster Name in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I am a newbie to Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), and I am trying to understand the object model behind it all with respect to clusters.

If I look at the clusters screen, I can see a list of my clusters :

[image]

But if I use the command line (kubectl), then I see something completely different :

[image]

Why are there two different types of cluster names? Which one is the correct cluster name?

Is it **cluster-2** or **gke_strange-vortex-286312_us-central1-c_cluster-2** ?

This is massively confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Naming scheme of `GKE` clusters found in `$ kubectl config get-contexts` is following:

- `gke_PROJECT-ID_ZONE_CLUSTER-NAME`

For **example**:

- `gke_AWESOME-PROJECT-123456_europe-west3-c_super-cluster`

---

**From the `GCP` perspective** the correct name is: `super-cluster`.

You will need to use the name pointed in either (they are the same):

- `Cloud Console` (UI)
- `$ gcloud container clusters list`

For example:

- `$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials super-cluster --zone=europe-west3-c`).

> It's important to use `--zone=ZONE` as there can be clusters named the same in different zones/regions.

Above command will fetch the cluster endpoint and auth data. It will also set the `~/.kube/config` to target `super-cluster`.

You don't need to use the `gke_PROJECT-ID_europe-west3-c_super-cluster` unless you would like to change context (which cluster are you issuing commands to) with `$ kubectl` and not `$ gcloud` command

The naming scheme used in `~/.kube/config` is used to distinguish one cluster (contexts wise) from another.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: SDK: Gcloud: Reference: Container: Clusters](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Cluster access for kubectl](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl)*