# EKS/AKS cluster name convention

Tags: python, kubernetes, naming-conventions, amazon-eks, azure-aks

I am writing a script that receives a Kubernetes context name as an input and outputs the different elements of the cluster ->

```
class GKE:
    def __init__(self, context):
        s = context.split("_")
        self.provider: str = s[0]
        self.project: str = s[1]
        self.data_center: GKE.DataCenter = GKE.DataCenter(data_center=s[2])
        self.cluster_name: str = s[3]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'provider: {self.provider}, project: {self.project}, {self.data_center}, cluster name: {self.cluster_name}'

    class DataCenter:
        def __init__(self, data_center: str):
            s = data_center.split("-")
            self.country: str = s[0]
            self.region: str = s[1]
            self.zone: str = s[2]

        def __str__(self):
            return f'country: {self.country}, region: {self.region}, zone: {self.zone}'

class EKS:
    # TODO: What are the fields? What is the convention?
    pass

class AKS:
    # TODO: What are the fields? What is the convention?
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(GKE(context="gke_XXX-YYY-ZZZ_us-central1-c_name"))
```

Output:

```
provider: gke, project: XXX-YYY-ZZZ, country: us, region: central1, zone: c, cluster name: name
```

This will support only the three main providers (GKE, EKS, AKS).

My question is:

What are the different elements of EKS and AKS context names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to differentiate between the correct name of the cluster and the naming schema of a resource.

When I run `kubectl config get-contexts` on the clusters Aks, Eks, and Gke I get the following results:

```
NAME                                               AUTHINFO
gke_project-1234_us-central1-c_myGKECluster        gke_project-1234_us-central1-c_myGKECluster  
myAKSCluster                                       clusterUser_myResourceGroup_myAKSCluster
arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:1234:cluster/myEKSCluster    arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:1234:cluster/myEKSCluster
```

In all three clouds, the correct name of the cluster in this example is `my***Cluster`.

The naming scheme in `~/.kube/config` is used to distinguish one cluster (contexts wise) from another.
For example when you want to change the context with kubectl, then you have to differentiate between cluster whose name is `myCluster` and is in `region-code1` Compared to another cluster whose name is also `myCluster` but he is in `region-code2`, and so on, so you will use the naming scheme.

**GKE:**

As you wrote, the naming scheme in gke consists of 4 parts: `provider_project-id_zone_cluster-name`
For example `gke_project-123_us-central1-c_myGKECluster`

- provider: `gke`
- project-id: `project-123`
- zone: `us-central1-c`
- cluster-name: `myGKECluster`

**AKS:**
In aks the naming schema is the name of the cluster.
But the `AUTHINFO`, (which is actually the configuration of the user in the kubeconfig file), consists of three parts: `Resource-type_Resource-group_Resource-name`
For example `clusterUser_myResourceGroup_myAKSCluster`

- The Resource-type is `clusterUser`
- The Resource-group is `myResourceGroup`
- The Resource-name is `myAKSCluster`

**EKS:**

> **AWS** requires an ARN when needed to specify a resource unambiguously across all of AWS.

The ARN format is `arn:partition:service:region:account-id:resource-type/resource-id`
For example `arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:1234:cluster/myEKSCluster`

- partition: the partition in which the resource is located (such as `aws` Regions).
- service: The service namespace that identifies the AWS product (such as `eks`).
- region: The Region code (such as `eu-west-1`).
- account-id: The ID of the AWS account that owns the resource(such as `1234`).
- resource-type: The resource type (such as `cluster`).
- resource-id The resource identifier. This is the name of the resource, the ID of the resource, or a resource path (such as `myEKSCluster`).

---

Additional resources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63824179/20571972
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-eks-cluster.html#aws-resource-eks-cluster-return-values